# Pythonic Enumerated list with attribute lookup, and list of values

Tags: python

A common idiom I have is something like this: (the iterator doesnt work btw):

```
SUMMARY = 'summary'
REPORT = 'report'

class PDF_TYPES:
    summary = SUMMARY
    report = REPORT

    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __iter__(self):
            return iter(list(self.summary, self.report))
```

Firstly thats a lot of boilerplate for 2 values.

I would like to define some constants in a list and be able to:

1. Refer to them individiually, e.g. `REPORT` as above
2. Import the whole list from another module, and refer to them as `PDF_TYPES.report` etc. A dictionary would be `import PDF_TYPES, REPORT; PDF_TYPES[REPORT]`, i.e. 2 imports to access one value is not nice.
3. As a list, e.g. `if x not in PDF_TYPES: raise ValueError(....)`.

I looked at dataclasses but they seem to be for instances of things, these are constants. A dictionary would be perfect except for the clunkiness in scneario 2, it doesnt have the attribute look up. What is the most pythonic way of achieving above 3 requirements?

Comment: Use an Enum? https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: You probably just want an enum, but note, `__iter__` should probably just be something like `yield self.summary; yield self.report`, you meant `iter([self.summary, self.report])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for that, buts its a class method so there is no self.

Comment: @run_the_race what?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you solution of `self.summary` includes the word `self`, but `PDF_TYPES` is not meant to be instantiated.

Comment: @run_the_race *in the metaclass `__iter__` man*. Instead of `return iter(list(self.summary, self.report))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like an enum is what you're describing

```
from enum import Enum
class PDF_TYPES(Enum):
    summary = 'summary'
    report = 'report'
```

then for example

```
>>> PDF_TYPES.summary
<PDF_TYPES.summary: 'summary'>

>>> for pdf_type in PDF_TYPES:
        print(pdf_type)
    
PDF_TYPES.summary
PDF_TYPES.report
```

Every enum entry has a `.name` and `.value` so if you want to check for containment you could use `any`

```
>>> any('report' == pdf_type.value for pdf_type in PDF_TYPES)
True
>>> any('foobar' == pdf_type.value for pdf_type in PDF_TYPES)
False
```

Comment: Great, except one can't test with say `'report' in PDF_TYPES`

Comment: @run_the_race I've updated my answer to address that. While not as simple as using `in` you could achieve this using `any`.